# SSH'ing to Linux Client using AWS command line in Jenkins

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, ssh

I need to SSH on to my Linux box from Jenkins using AWS cli. To do so, AWS documentation states I need to use my pem key:

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, Jenkins does not have access to where I have the pem file stored and moving it is not an option.

I have generated a sshagent in Jenkins using my pem file, but cannot find any documentation or examples that show how replacing the path to pem file with my sshagent would work.

Does anyone have any any idea what the syntax is or could be point me in the direction of some documentation on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed two questions or things:

1. to ssh you certainly need the .pem key but not to execute the aws cli. Use below for ssh from jenkins to ec2 instance.

Instead of doing the above you can update the EC2 instance ec2-user `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` with the public key of the jenkins user.

2. For executing aws cli commands if you want you need to use Access Credentials.